# Mysql Query : fetch data for weekly date info?

Tags: mysql

[image]

this is my DB table data,{ i have maintain only one Table}

i going to fetch only current week infrmation.

fetch max 3 datas from each start_date

give me any idea to develop query,,

Comment: If you have a table with the weeks in them that you can `JOIN` against, this would be a lot easier. MySQL is not very good at generating arbitrary sequences like that.

Comment: Please add more detail this question has waaaay to little information and will probably either get closed or never answered. We need to see the table structure and we need to see a query that you have tried.

Comment: see [date & time functions] (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html), you will need to use week() function to compare against the every row and current time (now()), group them. This is the basic idea

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT eventid, fkUserid, event_tags, event_title, event_description, start_date, end_date 
FROM (SELECT eventid, fkUserid, event_tags, event_title, event_description, start_date, end_date, 
            IF(start_date = @last, @auto:=@auto+1, @auto:=0) cnt, IF(start_date != @last, @last:=start_date, TRUE) test
        FROM (SELECT eventid, fkUserid, event_tags, event_title, event_description, DATE(start_date) start_date, end_date 
            FROM event WHERE DATE(start_date) BETWEEN '2012-12-14' AND '2012-12-20' ORDER BY start_date) AS A, 
          (SELECT @auto:=0, @last:='0001-01-01') AS B
        ) AS A
WHERE cnt < 3;
```